# Upon login, it redirect me back to login form

Tags: php

Login.php

```
    <?php 
        include 'config/database.php';
        include 'functions/functions.php';
        $Db = "users";
        $user = $_POST['emailaddress'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        login($user, $pass, $con, $Db);
        ?>
```

Functions.php

```
    if (!function_exists('login')) { 
  function login($user, $pass, $link, $db){

      if(!$link->select_db($db)){
        echo "Failed Database";
      }

     if(!empty($_POST)){
      $person = sanitize($user, "html", $link);
      $secret = sanitize($pass, "html", $link);
      $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND pass = ?";

      if (!$stmt = $link->prepare($query)) {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $link->errno . ") " . $link->error;
      }
      $stmt->bind_param('ss', $person, $secret);

      if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
      }

      $result = $stmt->get_result();
      $stmt->store_result();
      $check = $result->num_rows;

      if($check){
        $items = $result->fetch_assoc();
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;

        echo "why cant it lead to view_record.php";

        //header("Location: view_record.php");

      }
      else{
        header("Location: index.php?error=true");
      }

        exit;
        $query->free_result();
        $link->close();
    }

  }
}
```

HTML login

```
<form id="login" name="login-form" method="POST" action="login.php">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="emailaddress">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Email Address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-login">Login</button>
</form>
```

Echo "why cant it lead to view_record.php" showed when try login. But if use header, it does not lead me to view page and instead redirect me to login form page. Before it worked, then changed codes inside function login and it doesn't work anymore. Not sure why header is not working anymore.

Help appreciated!

**Update - view_record.php**

```
  <body>
  <?php include 'layout/header.php' ?>
  <div class="container center-block">
    <h1>View List</h1>


       <?php
            include 'config/database.php';
            include 'functions/functions.php';
            if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {

                viewList("test", "id", $con);
              }
            else{
              header("Location: index.php"); 
            }       
       ?>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: why its in comment? //header("Location: view_record.php");

Comment: @RuchishParikh - yes i tested with header and it took me back to login form. So I commented it first and tested to see if echo shows. It worked but problem is when login and it verify and then it should take me to view page.

Comment: You need to execute `session_start()` at the top of your script.

Comment: Can you show what is code on `view_record.php`.

Comment: also try to check its going in else condition or not?

Comment: @Peter - execute on which file?

Comment: @RuchishParikh - eh there is condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some small changes to your code:

```
<?php

session_start();

include 'config/database.php';
include 'functions/functions.php';

$Db = "users";

$user = $_POST['emailaddress'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

login($user, $pass, $con, $Db);

?>

Functions.php

if (!function_exists('login')) {
    function login($user, $pass, $link, $db) {
        if (!$link->select_db($db)) {
            echo "Failed Database";
        }

        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $person = sanitize($user, "html", $link);
            $secret = sanitize($pass, "html", $link);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND pass = ?";

            if (!$stmt = $link->prepare($query)) {
                echo "Prepare failed: (" . $link->errno . ") " . $link->error;
            }
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $person, $secret);

            if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
            }

            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $check = $result->num_rows;

            if ($check) {
                $items = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;

                echo "why cant it lead to view_record.php";

                //header("Location: view_record.php");

                // # -- Line added
                exit;

            } else {
                header("Location: index.php?error=true");

                // # -- Line added
                exit;
            }

            // This exit is not necassary
            exit;

            // This will never be executed
            $query->free_result();
            $link->close();
        }
    }
}
```

However this won't fix your problem. The only reason why it keeps redirecting could be because either your database connection is incorrect or it doesn't return the correct results. You can debug this by using `var_dump()` and `exit;` throughout your code seeing where it goes wrong.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks i have been at it for several hours. and will try

Comment: @joe Please try commenting out all `header("Locations: ...")` functions. This way your script will display errors and you'll know what to fix.